# Как рисовать полупрозрачный лини на Canvas без наложения цвета?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Всем привет у меня тут образовалась проблема.
Я делаю небольшую рисовалку и по заданию нужно чтобы можно было на канве рисовать линии с разным уровнем прозрачности.
Вот тут пример такой рисовалки:
https://jsfiddle.net/08cw6mh7/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('paint'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 10;
var drag= false;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

$("#paint").mousedown(function(e){
drag = true;
});


$("#paint").mousemove(function(e){
 if (drag){
ctx.lineWidth = radius*2; 
ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(50,100,150,.25)"  
ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);  
ctx.stroke();


  
ctx.beginPath();  
ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(50,100,150,.25)"
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)


}
});

$("#paint").mouseup(function(e){
drag = false ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paint" style="display: block"></canvas>
```

проблема следующая: если рисовать поставить цвет заливки например rgba (50, 100, 150, 1) то все работает хорошо так как прозрачность 1. И при перемещении мыши, цвета хоть и накладываются друг на друга, но за счет полной непрозрачности это не заметно. Но если начать изменять прозрачность например rgba (50, 100, 150, .25) то начинается треш - цвета начинают накладываться и получается не равномерно-прозрачная линя а непонятно что. Что можно сделать?

Comment: пример конвертилки из цвета с прозрачностью в цвет без прозрачности с учетом фона: http://yolijn.com/convert-rgba-to-rgb

Answer (score 1):

Дополню комментарий Grundy.
Дополнил Ваш код функцией по его ссылке.
Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('paint');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 10;
var drag = false;
var alpha = 0.25;

var range = document.getElementById('alpha');
range.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  alpha = parseFloat(this.value);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  drag = true;
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  drag = false;
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (drag) {
    var offset = $(canvas).offset();
    var x = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var y = e.clientY - offset.top;

    var color = combineColors([255, 255, 255], [50, 100, 150, alpha]);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

  }
}, false);

function combineColors(bg, color) {
  var a = color[3];
  var r = Math.round((1 - a) * bg[0] + a * color[0]);
  var g = Math.round((1 - a) * bg[1] + a * color[1]);
  var b = Math.round((1 - a) * bg[2] + a * color[2]);
  var color = [r, g, b].join();
  return 'rgb(' + color + ')';
}
```

```css
#paint {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paint"></canvas>
<input id="alpha" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.25">
```